# How to find universal covering space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

If our topological space is connected, locally connected and semi-locally simply-connected, then we know that a universal cover exists. Knowing the existence, my question is how to find universal cover explicitly? Any help in this regard will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any construction other than hatcher?I find it quite long construction ...

Comment: I don't find Hatcher's construction long at all. It puts a nice topology on the set of homotopy classes of paths on $X$. The verification of simple connectedness might be a bit tedious, but I don't see what else is "long" there.

Answer (score 2):

This question is related to this [stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/826031/how-do-you-construct-the-lifted-topology-of-a-groupoid-cover) and answer on lifted topologies.

An algebraic model of a  covering map is a **covering groupoid morphism**, $q: H \to G $, namely a groupoid morphism  such that for each $x \in  Ob(H)$ and $g$ from $q(x)$  to some $y$ there is a unique $h$ in $H$ starting at $x$ such that $q(h)=g$.

If $p: X \to B$ is a covering map, then the induced morphism of groupoids $\pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(B)$ is a covering morphism of groupoids.

If $G$ is a connected groupoid, then an easy construction of a *universal covering groupoid* of $G$ is to choose $x \in Ob(G)$ and let $Ob(H)$ be the set of elements of $G$ starting at $x$, with $Ob(q)$ being the end point map. An element of $H(g,g')$ is to be a pair  $(h,g)$ of elements of $G$  such that $hg=g'$.

Note that this construction if $G=\pi_1(B)$ requires no conditions on $B$. It is the construction of the lifted topology which requires the local conditions.